# Finding the area of the 4th triangle, given the areas of the other 3, and all the 4 form a rectangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, packing-problem, rectangles

In one of my tutorial classes, when I was studdying in 9th class (I am in 10th now), our tutor gave us a problem saying it’s a difficult one, and to him, *it was incomplete*.

This is *that* problem:

> **In a rectangle *ABCD*, point *B* is joined to the points *P* and *Q* on the sides *AD* and *DC* respectively. And *P* and *Q* are joined to form *three* distinct triangle; namely *PDQ or x*, *QCB or y*, *BAP or z* and *BPQ or f*.**
>
> **Given the area of *x = 3m^2*, *y = 4m^2* and *z = 5m^2*, find the area of *f*.**
>
> **Note:** all the information regarding this problem has been provided. The dimensions of any of the line segments are *not known*. This also means that the exact positions of  *P* and *Q*  on their respective line segments are also *not known*.
>   [image: diagram]

Because of the lack of information (See *Note*), my tutor declared it as an incomplete problem (he is just a high-school Science and Mathematics teacher, please don’t expect him to think beyond the limits of a typical high-school student, that is, in case he is wrong).

After a few hours of brainstorming, I came up with what I called an *ingenious method*. But then I felt that my method actually was not accurate.

**So, can anybody tell me if this problem is complete and solvable, if yes, is my method correct (see below), if no, what is the best/better method to solve it.**

---

### MY METHOD:

> As all the triangles with their areas given are on the edge of the rectangle, we know that they all are *right triangles*. So we can say that one of the arms of *the right angle* is *the altitude* and the other is *the base*.
>
> Now, we can use the formula *(1/2) * base * altitude* to calculate their areas. Lets take *a* as *altitude* and *b* as *base*.
>
> (Here’s the first part of *the trick*) We now try all possible _a_s and _b_s for the three triangles, where *a* and *b* are **natural numbers only**. (This is also where the major weakness of my method is. More numbers, i.e., any *real numbers* should have been tried, but that is infeasible). Note that *all possible values* are those values that form a triangle of that specified area.
>
> **For triangle *x*, we have the following dimensions:**
>   -***a = 1*, *b = 6***
>   -*a = 2*, *b = 3*
>   -*a = 3*, *b = 2*
>   -*a = 6*, *b = 1* #
>
> **For triangle *y*, we have the following dimensions:**
>   -*a = 1*, *b = 8*
>   -***a = 2*, *b = 4***
>   -*a = 4*, *b = 2*#
>   -*a = 8*, *b = 1*
>
> **For triangle *z*, we have the following dimensions:**
>   -***a = 1*, *b = 10***
>   -*a = 2*, *b = 5*
>   -*a = 5*, *b = 2*
>   -*a = 10*, *b = 1*#
>
> (Here’s the other part of the trick) Then, we select those specific dimensions of triangles, which when placed together form a rectangle.
>
> **The condition we require:**
>   **When the triangles are placed together to form a *quadrilateral* the opposite sides of it must be equal.**
>
> If this *quadrilateral’s* opposite sides are equal, we know that it is a *parallelogram*. And as all of the triangles that form the edges are *right angled*, we have at least one of the angles of the *parallelogram* right angled_, so we know that this *parallelogram* is a *rectangle*.
>
> The correct set of dimensions (that we will be using here) are high-lighted in bold, while the once suffixed with a ‘#’ can also be used.
>
> So, in *triangle x* we take *PD* as altitude and *DQ* as base.
>   In *triangle y* we take *BC* as altitude and *CQ* as base.
>   In *triangle z* we take *PA* as altitude and *AB* as base.
>
> Henceforth, we now have:
>   *(PA + PD) = BC*
>   *(DQ + CQ) = AB*
>   Therefore, the condition is matched.
>
> **WE NOW HAVE THE CORRECT DIMENSIONS OF THE THREE TRIANGLES**
>
> Now we can either find the area of *f* by finding the area of the rectangle and subtracting it by the areas of the three triangles, or by finding the three triangle’s *hypotenuse* using the *Pythagorean formula* and then apply the _Herron’s formula _on the hypotenuses. I prefer the former.
>
> ### >*After calculating, we have, _f = 8m^2_*

Thank you =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Let BC = 1 unit. Then, $4 = y = [\triangle CBQ] = \frac {1.QC}{2}$ yields QC = 8 units

Let DQ = s units. Then AB = s + 8 units

$5 = z = [\triangle ABP] = \frac {(s+8).AP}{2}$ yields $AP = \frac {10}{s + 8}$ units

$DP = 1 – AP = … = \frac {s – 2}{s + 8}$

Similarly, $3 = (\frac {1}{2}) {s}{\frac{ s – 2}{s + 8}}$.

The above result is a solvable quadratic with roots $s = 12$ or $–4$ (rejected)

Therefore, the rectangle occupies 20 square units and x, y, z occupy …. Giving f = ...

Comment: How do you justify the BC = 1 assertion? With that you show there is one solution but how do you know this is the only one?

Comment: @GertBeukema This is called **unitisation**. I will use length as an example. I have the right to declare the length of an object (say 3.52 cm) as an equivalent to 1 (special) unit [defined by me]. Thus, another object which is 26.048 cm long is equal to 7.4 times of my (special) units. Also, I think the solution is unique (as the proof shows). Other possible candidate is the rejected one.

Comment: But there are other solutions, e.g. AB = 5, BC = 4 or 10 and 2 or 6 2/3 and 3.

Comment: The problem I see with your unitization here is that you still keep using 3,4 and 5 as the areas, so these are now not unitized. With BC = 1 you are only looking at one specific case, which luckily for you has a solution.

Comment: @GertBeukema Note that the question is asking what f is (rather than the dimension of the rectangle). Thus, your suggested candidates need not be distinguished. For you latest comment:- Choosing one particular portion to be unitized can do the job already. Hence, there is no need to unitize the area too. Besides, one has to be very careful in unitizing more than one dimension because conflict might occur.

Comment: @GertBeukema Agree that if the contributions of x, y, z are not that “perfect”, I might come up with a more difficult quadratic. Judging from the solvable nature of the question, that quadratic should then be solvable, although it might contain some irrational root k. T, the area is then 1.(k + QC [a known quantity because of y]) square units. f is still given by T – (the portion occupied by x) – (...y) – (...z). There is no luckiness involved unless the combination of x, y, z makes the question unsolvable.

Comment: But how do you know that if there are solution(s), choosing BC = 1 is one of them. How do you know that different dimensions lead to the same answer?

Comment: @GertBeukema You can also start from AB = 1, Then, AP = 10. Let PD = t. BC = 10 + t, and so on. You will endup with t = 10 making the area of the rectangle = 20 square units. This will still give f the same answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22676/discussion-between-gert-beukema-and-mick).

Comment: @Mick May I choose also PQ=1?

Comment: @san Based on the fact that the lengths of the lines are relative to each other, I think you can. However, the computation will be more complicated.

Comment: But PQ is the hypotenuse of a triangle of area x=3, then it is greater than each of its catheti, hence the area of the triangle is less than 1/2?

Comment: Now I understand:You can choose a vertical side or a horizontal to be 1, because you can apply 
a linear transformation of $\Bbb{R}^2$ given by $x\mapsto \lambda x$ and 
$y\mapsto y/\lambda$. This yields a new rectangle and the areas of $x,y,z$ 
don't change, so you have the same situation again. 
 Then for $\lambda:=$BD, you obtain the problem with B'D'=1 and for 
$\lambda=$1/AB you obtain a rectangle with AB=1. 
But you cannot choose a diagonal side to be 1, the transformation involved would not 
preserve the areas, or would not preserve the right angles.

Comment: @san First of all, the question is asking for the dimension of the rectangle only. This means the unknown should either be the length (or the breadth). After unitisation, we can let the length (or the breadth) be 1. It is hard to imagine why start by setting the hypotenuse to 1. The transformation interpretation is correct but I cannot agree with the last part. According to my calculation (using your approach), I still have DQ:QC = 3:2 and AP:PD = 1:1 in accordance with my posted answer. Looking from another angle, my ⊿BQC is **similar** to yours except mine is $\sqrt {8^2 + 1^2}$ times bigger

Comment: Yes, you can have only one of them equal to 1, not both at the same time.

Comment: If you multiply for example the vertical sides with 2, you must divide the horizontal sides by 2.

Comment: @san Referring to your comment on “can have only one of them equal to 1, not both…”, I would like to point out that it is an important practice in unitization. Think of it from another angle, if both were being set equal to 1, then the figure is a ***square*** now—violating the given condition. Worst of all, even if the suggested answer is obtained, it also works for a special case only. The whole proof is invalid because it is not general enough.

Answer (score 3):

Let BC = h and AB = k

QC = 8/h (since area BCQ = 4)

AP = 10/k (since area ABP = 5)

(h - 10/k)(k - 8/h) = 6 (since area DPQ = 3)

Now: k = 20/h or k = 4/h (h <> 0)

Since the area of the rectangle is k*h and larger than 12 we have to disregard the second solution.

Using the first solution we get 20 as the area of the rectangle and f = 8.

Since there only is one solution, I'd call the problem complete.

Comment: You should include the computation:
$$
(h - 10/k)(k - 8/h) = 6
$$
$$
(hk-10)(hk-8)=6hk
$$
$$
(hk)^2-24 hk+80=0
$$
$$
(hk-20)(hk-4)=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic problem! Thanks for sharing. I solved it with Euler Math Toolbox (see below). However, I'd like to see a more geometric solution. Probably, I am just blind right now.

The method of the solution is straightforward. $xh$ is $x$ depending on $a$ and $b$ (computing the area as side times side divided by 2). $fh$ is $f$ depending on $a$, $b$, $z$ and $y$. Then, surprisingly, we can get rid of the total area  $a*b=x+y+z+f$

```
>xh &= (b-2*z/a)*(a-2*y/b)/2
```

$${ (a - {{2y} \over b} ) (b - {{2z} \over a} )} \over 2$$

```
>fh &= expand(a*b-(xh+y+z))
```

$$ {{ab} \over 2} - {{2yz} \over {ab}}$$

```
>fhh &= subst(x+y+z+f,a*b,fh)
```

$$ {{z + y + x + f} \over 2} - {{ 2yz} \over {z + y + x + f}} $$

```
>&solve(f=fhh,f), function f(x,y,z) &= f with %[2]
```

$$ [ {f = -\sqrt {z^2 - 2yz + 2xz + y^2 + 2xy + x^2}, f = \sqrt {z^2 - 2yz + 2xz + y^2 + 2xy + x^2}} ] $$

$$ \sqrt {x^2 - 2yz +2xz + y^2 + 2xy + x^2} $$

```
>f(3,4,5)
```

$$ 8 $$

Answer (score 1):

This problem is complete in that we are given all of the required information to solve it.

Let a = |AB| = |CD| and b = |BC| = |DA| since ABCD is a rectangle

Let |CQ| = qa so |QD| = (1 - q)a

Let |DP| = pb so |PA| = (1 - p)b

Given the areas of the 3 triangles we then have (after multiplying both sides by 2)

(1) 10 = (1 - p)ab   from area of z is 5

(2) 8 = qab          from area of y is 4

(3) 6 = (1-q)pab     from area of x is 6

From (2) we have q = 8/ab and substituting into (3) we have p = 6(ab - 8)

Substituting into (1) we have 10 = [1 - (6/(ab - 8))]ab which can be rearranged to give the quadratic equation

(ab)^2 - 24ab + 80 = 0 or (ab - 4)(ab - 20) = 0

We can reject the root ab = 4 since this gives a negative area for triangle f, so we have [area of f] = 20 - 3 - 4 - 5 = 8

For extra points we could go on the solve for p and q, getting p = 1/2 and q = 2/5

Comment: Sorry, I missed a divide by sign in my answer, it should be p = 6/(ab - 8) not 6(ab - 8)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Let B = the length of line BC.
Let H = the length of line AB.
Then line AP = 4/z.
Then Line CQ = 8/y.
Let R = B*H = the area of the rectangle ABCD.
Then H = R/B.

Let R = B*H  (area of the rectangle = Base * Height).

If you mirror the 3 outside triangles (z,x,y) about their hypotenuse to create smaller rectangles inside R and sum the areas of these 3 rectangles, you get the area of the rectangle (R), plus some overlap.  The area of overlap is (z/H)*(y/B).

2*(z+x+y) - (z/H)*(y/B) = B*H

or

2*z+2*x+2*y-z*y/R = R

We how have 1 equation and 1 unknown R (where R = the area of ABCD).    At this point the problem is effectively solved.

To continue to the final solution, convert the equation into a  more conventional form by multiplying both sides by -R, then adding R^2 to both sides, then use the quadratic formula to solve for R.

R^2-2*R*x-2*R*y-2*R*z+y*z = 0

Only the larger of the two solutions for R has physical significance. After simplification you get:

f := sqrt( (z+x+y)^2 - 4*(z*y) )    <==============================

Plug in any values you want for x, y, and z; and get the area f.

Note:  This solution does not require the knowledge of any lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P = (0, 2), Q = (3, 0)$ and $B = (a,b)$ to force $x = 3$. Using the shoelace formula, the area of $\Delta PQB$ is $\frac{1}{2}(3b+2a-6)$, which is equal to the area of the rectangle minus the three smaller triangles, or $ab - (3+4+5)$.

Thus $3b+2a-6 = 2ab - 24$, or $2ab - 2a - 3b - 18 = 0$. This factors as $(2a-3)(b-1) = 21$, and as $B$ must have a larger $x$-coordinate than $Q$, and a larger $y$-coordinate than $P$, the only option is the pair $(7, 3)$ which gives $a = 5, b = 4$. Thus the area is $\frac{1}{2}(3b+2a-6) = \boxed{8}$.